# How to bind FormGroup object to ModelClass object

Tags: angular

On Button click i have to post and send student object,
 so pls tell me how to bind formGroup object to ModelClass Object,
 dont want to add manually data one by one to variable. 
 I have to bind with single way not manually.

**This is my formGroup Object**

```
this.AMform = fb.group({ 

            "Name": new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ]),
            "Code":new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ]),
            "Address": new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ])

        });
```

**This is my model**

```
class Student 
{        
    public Name: string="";
    public Code: string="";
    public Äddress: string="";

}
```

Answer (score 6):

On button click you can do following :

```
onClick(){
  let student = new Student();
  student = this.AMform.value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The currently highest-rated answer creates an object, assigns it to a variable, and assigns another object to that variable in the next line, causing the previously created object to be garbage collected. This doesn't make a lot of sense.

The problem with assigning a `FormGroup`'s value to a class instance is that `AbstractFormGroup.value` has type `any`. This means, your compiler won't complain about any type mismatch which is the reason the code in the highest-rated answer actually compiles.

Let me show three different ways, one can deal with this issue:

## Quick and dirty

Simply cast the `value` of the `FormGroup` to the desired class:

```js
onClick() {
  let student: Student = this.AMform.value as Student;
}
```

Don't forget that this will be Javascript at runtime and Javascript is not typesafe and will not care if the properties of the `value` object match the fields of your `Student` class.

If you can be sure that the `FormControls` of your `FormGroup` will always match the fields of your `Student` class, use this approach.

## With `Object.assign`

Another option would be to use `Object.assign`. This has the benefit that properties that are part of your `Student` class but are not present in the `value` object will be present in the final object. However, if `AMfom.value` contains additional properties that are not part of your `Student` class, they will still end up in the final object.

```js
onClick() {
  let student: Student = Object.assign(new Student(), this.AMform.value);
}

// e.g. for {Name: 'Foo', Code: 'Bar'}, we will get {Name: 'Foo', Code: 'Bar', Address: ''}
// BUT for {Name: 'Foo', Age: 25}, we will get {Name: 'Foo', Code: '', Address: '', Age: 25}
```

**Note:** This will only work if all class fields are initialized on object initialization.

## Casting manually

The drawback with `Object.assign()` is that it will assign any properties to an object even if this property is not a field of the object's class. To deal with this issue, you can write your own casting function. This function assigns properties only if they are present in both objects.

```js
function castAny<T>(target: T, source: object): T {
  const result: T = Object.assign({}, target);
  Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
      result[key] = source[key];
    }
  });
  return result;
}

onClick() {
  let student: Student = castAny(new Student(), this.AMform.value);
}

// for {Name: 'Foo', Age: 25}, we will get {Name: 'Foo', Code: '', Address: ''}
```

**Note:** This will only work if all class fields are initialized on object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Do you click:

```
manterDados() {
    console.log(this.inquilinoForm.value);
    this.inquilino = this.inquilinoForm.value;
    console.log(this.inquilino);
  }
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

this is and other solucion

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formGroup.value))
```

if all controls of formGroup have the same name of the obj